# Android - LED Notification doesn't blink

Tags: android

I'm desperately trying to add a notification feature to my application making the notification LED blink. After all my attempts nothing works ...

Here's my code :

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 200, 200)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
            .setColor(getColor(R.color.buttonBlueInactive))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    manager.notify(1, notification.build());
}
```

If anyone could help, it would be really appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

For those who have the same problem that I had, there is the solution :

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 200, 200)
            // Add the line bellow
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
            .setColor(getColor(R.color.buttonBlueInactive))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    manager.notify(1, notification.build());
}
```

Comment: Try to increase the timer for tests... Change from 200 to 2000 just to test if change something.

Comment: Just tried it but and it didn't work ..

Comment: Ok. You are getting the notification at least, right? Just the LED which is not blinking right?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

If I'm not wrong, you are missing `setDefaults()`

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 200, 200)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS) // Add this line
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
            .setColor(getColor(R.color.buttonBlueInactive))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    manager.notify(1, notification.build());
}
```

In the example above, I added following options:

```
Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
```

You may want to change according to your need. More info:

[Android DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDefaults(int))

**Option 2**

If example above does not work, try the code below:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 200, 200)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
            .setColor(getColor(R.color.buttonBlueInactive))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Notification builtNotification = notification.build();
    builtNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    manager.notify(1, builtNotification);
}
```

Comment: Will you marry me ? I just spent my whole day trying to fix it ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Good to know.. Please, let me know which of the codes above worked for you.. just for future references...

Comment: It's the first one